# building this not-so-necessary relationship is a good approach?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, relational-theory

I created a database for an app, where I have several networks, which have several nodes and elements and also several scenarios, all related to the networks. [see picture below]

My question is: since the `sce_results` and `sce_paramaters` will have result and parameter information of the `nodes` and `elements` of a network, should I also build this relationship between the `nodes` & `elements` tables and `sce_results` & `sce_paramaters` tables via foreign-keys?

or since it gets complicated, the way I created the tables are fine? Maybe more general question, when it is good to build these relationships via the foreign-keys?

So far I though since `nodes` & `elements` have their names, I can match them with the `name` columns in `sce_results` & `sce_paramaters` tables, after I download all the necessary data for doing further calculations or creating result plots, etc... Therefore I do not really need this relationship from my point of view. What do you think?

Example:

```
Network1: Nodes: [Node1, Node2, Node3]
          Elements: [Element1, Element2]
          Scenarios: [ScenarioX]
ScenarioX: Paramater: [Pressure_Node1 = 5, Pressure_Node2 = 10, ...]
           Result: [Flow_Node1 = 100, ...]

# In this case nodes table looks like:
id | net_id | name | ... | x | y
1    1        Node1
2    1        Node2
...      

# In this case sce_parameter table looks like:
id | sce_id | name | extension | value | unit
1    1        Node1  Pressure    5
2    1        Node2  Pressure    10
...
```

[image: DB-Diagram]

Comment: I am not entirely certain what you mean by "`sce_results` and `sce_paramaters` will have result and parameter information of the `nodes` and `elements`", but if each `sco_results` is related to a certain `nodes`, there should certainly be a foreign key.

Comment: these table represents the parameter and result information of all nodes and all elements inside a network. Do you think it is necessary also to add the network_id inside  the sce_parameters and sce_results?

Comment: I have no idea how these tables represent the parameter information. I guess I would need way more explanation; I am a bit dense when it comes to guessing these things. I see no columns that would indicate a relationship.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added an example in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the `name` of a `nodes` row in `sce_parameters` is a bad idea indeed. Store the primary key of the `nodes` row instead and add a foreign key constraint. This will guarantee that you cannot end up with inconsistent data.

Comment: do you think, it is also necessary to add `net_id` to the `sce_parameters` or since it has `sce_id` and connected to networks over scenarios (where scenarios are connected to network via `net_id`) already accomplish this?

Comment: The indirect relationship via `nodes` is enough. A direct foreign key to `networks` would be redundant and consequently harmful.